# How to get a reason of failure in Android's Google Drive API

Tags: android, kotlin, gdrive

Is there any way to find out what was a reason of Google Drive API failure when onFailure callback is called with exception error message set to null? Is it even a legit approach for developers of API's to throw exceptions without any specific subclassing and without any information about the reason of the failure?

In my view, this is just a bug caused by poor coding style and deteriorating s/w development culture at Google, but let me know otherwise, probably I'm missing the latest trends in contemporary agile methodologies used by Google.

It's not clear what to show to a user in this case, except that obscure and confusing, but unfortunately very common "Unknown GDrive Error" message.

```
 Tasks.call(mExecutor, Callable<Int>{
        var pageToken: String? = null

        var textFound = false
        var otherFound = false
        var cnt = 0

        do {
            val q = mDrive!!.files().list()
                    .setQ("name='some-text' or name='other-text'")
                    .setSpaces("drive")
                    .setFields("nextPageToken, files(id, name)")
                    .setPageToken(pageToken)
                    .setOrderBy("modifiedTime desc")

            val files = q.execute()

            for (file in files.getFiles()) {
                textFound = file.name.equals("some-text")
                otherFound = file.name.equals("other-text")
            }
            pageToken = files.nextPageToken
        } while (pageToken != null)

        cnt += if (plainFound) 1 else 0
        cnt += if (encFound) 1 else 0

        return@Callable cnt

    }).addOnFailureListener { it: Exception

        // it.message is equal to NULL here and I don't know what to tell the user
        // except that obscure "Unknown GDrive Error"
    }
```

Comment: You can read the exception's code and search it on Google, they have a list of all possible errors and their codes

Comment: @Ahmad Please provide more details about how to get code since it could be a valid answer. Do I need downcast Exception to something else in this case? To what exactly? There is no "code" in the generic Exception object that failureListener receives.

Comment: You can put a debug point in onFailure and see the properties of the exception object